# CSS formatted by jQuery not applying to hidden elements?

Tags: jquery, css

I am applying CSS to some elements and I have them display: none; and whenever a user clicks on a radio button, it will take the display: none; off the element and show it.

However, I have CSS applied to those elements THROUGH jQuery. Whenever the page is loaded.. the width is not applied. I have setwidth(1/2) or something and it'll find the width of the parent div, cut it in half, and set that width to that. HOWEVER since the whole div is displayed to none, as soon as the page is loaded, it won't even GRAB that jquery function to do that... so the width is 0px.. and whenever I load the DIV, it.. is all effed up and is basically just a huge 0px width DIV.

How do I go about doing this?

Ok where I'm at, the wifi as JFiddle filtered and blocked access to it.
But here is my markup:

HTML:

```
<fieldset id="new_item">
    <legend>New Item</legend>
    <div class="input-row">
        <div class="input-wrap setwidth(1/2)">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductDescription, T("Product Description (maximum of 30 characters"))
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductDescription, new { @class = "setwidth(1)", @maxlength = "30" })
        </div>
        <div class="input-wrap setwidth(1/2)">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductClass, T("Product Class"))
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductClass, new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(Model.ProductClasses, "Value", "Key"), new { @class = "setwidth(1)" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

And there is more, but then here is my jQuery and CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.hide { display: none; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#new_item').addClass('hide');
        $('#existing_item').addClass('hide');
        $('#StateOfItem').change(function () {
            //every time value of StateOfItem is changed
            if ($('.new_item').is(':checked')) {
                $('#new_item').removeClass('hide');
                $('#existing_item').addClass('hide');
            }
            else if ($('.existing_item').is(':checked')) {
                $('#new_item').addClass('hide');
                $('#existing_item').removeClass('hide');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code and markup?

Comment: Show us your code, HTML, CSS and jQuery.  Better yet, make a jsFiddle

Comment: Please include some code, or a JSFiddle link.  It is nearly impossible to provide an accurate answer without code inspection/testing.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Display property set to none doesn't keep 'space' of elements.
You should use visibility instead:

```
$('#myelem').css('visibility','hidden');
$('#myelem').css('visibility','visible');
```

Comment: Yeah I did that, but then it adds the obnoxious space that the form would of originally taken up underneath the main form... like the submit button is pushed way underneath the other form. I'm hiding a sub form from the main form... and visibility just doesn't cut it D: I tried that. It fixes the problem, BUT it adds a huge obnoxious white space on my page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm always using function like this:

```
    function getBlockWidth(block) {
        var oldStyle = block.attr('style');
        block.css({
            'display' : 'block',
            'visibility' : 'hidden',
            'position' : 'absolute'
        });
        var h = block.outerWidth();
        block
            .removeAttr('style')
            .attr('style', oldStyle);
        return h;
    }
```

Usage:

```
var someItemWidth = getBlockWidth( $('#new_item') );
```

You can rewrite it to jQuery plugin, but Im using it as method of my helper object.